# Postgres write through apache beam

Tags: postgresql, apache-beam

When trying to write to postgres through Apache beam I am getting
`java.io.NotSerializableException: org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection`.

As suggested in [docs](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/jdbc/JdbcIO.html) I am using this code , `JdbcIO.DataSourceConfiguration.create("org.postgresql.Driver",connectionUrl);`

I can read the data from postgres table but write is throwing this error, write is using the same configuration . Any suggestions ?

Comment: What does your pipeline look like besides creating the configuration? Is there any PCollection that contains some type that is or has a member of`org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection`? If you need to pass `org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection` around, it needs to implement Serializable.

Comment: pCollection.apply(JdbcIO.<KV<String,BigDecimal>>write().withDataSourceConfiguration(jdbcConfig)
        .withStatement("insert into test_table values(?,?)")
        .withPreparedStatementSetter(new JdbcIO.PreparedStatementSetter<KV<String, BigDecimal>>() {
            @Override
            public void setParameters(KV<String, BigDecimal> kv, PreparedStatement query)
                    throws SQLException {
                query.setString(1, kv.getKey());
                query.setBigDecimal(2, kv.getValue());
            }
        }));